# About the Artin symbol

Tags: class-field-theory

Let $L$ be a finite abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $m$ be a positive integer such that $L\subset\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $m$-th root of unity. Let $a$ be an integer coprime to $m$. Then the *Artin symbol* $(\frac{L}{a})$ is the automorphism of $L$ obtained by restricting to $L$ the automorphism $\phi$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ determined by $(\zeta\mapsto\zeta^a)$.

My question is, why is, $\phi(L)\subset L$?

Comment: what are your thoughts?

Comment: Hint: what does it mean for an extension to be abelian?

Comment: @Wojowu: Thanks for the hint. $\phi$ restricts to a $\mathbb{Q}$-homomorphism of $L\to\phi(L)$. Since $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois, $\phi(L)\subset L$. Is this correct? Also, it seems to me that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}$ is not always a cyclic Galois extension, right?

Comment: This is correct. Cyclotomic extensions are always Galois (note the conjugates of $\zeta$ are powers of $\zeta$)

Comment: Also, I think the Artin symbol $(\frac{L}{a})$ depends not only on $a$, but also on $m$, am I right?

Comment: That is a good follow up question, sai (+1). Initially one might think that it also depends on $m$, but actually it doesn't in the following sense. If we view some other cyclotomic field containing $L$, say $\Bbb{Q}(\xi)$ where $\xi$ is a primitive root of unity of order $\ell$, where $m\mid \ell$ so that $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta)\subseteq \Bbb{Q}(\xi)$. Then the automorphism of $\Bbb{Q}(\xi)$ that maps $\xi\mapsto\xi^a$ is an extension of the automorphism $\zeta\mapsto\zeta^a$.

Comment: There is scope for some ambguity in the sense that some other automorphism $\xi\mapsto \xi^b$, $b\neq a$, may also extend $\zeta\mapsto\zeta^a$. But, obviously both of those automorphisms have the same restriction to $L$, so this doesn't really matter.

Comment: The upshot is that the action on roots of unity gives a sort of uniform way of putting something like a *coordinate* on the abelian Galois groups over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: Thank you for the explanations.